# Jinja2 and Vuejs binding href attribute

Tags: flask, vue.js, vuejs2, jinja2

I want to pass a variable from Vue instance to an href attribute in jinja2.
So I want to do something like this:

```
<a :href="{{ url_for('slugwhatever', **{'name': name}) }}">Go to your page!</a>
```

Where the second `name` is the variable I want to get from Vue.
Either jinja2 or Vue keep throwing errors because they interpolate with each other.
How can I make this work? Is there any good approach to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<a :href="'{{ url_for('slugwhatever') }}/' + name">Go to your page!</a>
```

Or:

```
<a :href="'{{ url_for('slugwhatever', {'name': ''}) }}/' + name">Go to your page!</a>
```

Comment: Note: I have an input with v-model on that `name`. I have done both and got /NaN on the `<a/>`.

Comment: Can you add {{ name }} like `... name">Go to your page! {{ name }}</a>` just to debug? What does it show?

Comment: For whatever reason now it's working, but I get an url like: `/slugwhatever//<name>` (with double forward slash, the flask url mapping it's not recognizing it). Notes: I set delimiters for Vue to: `@{}`. I had a bug with Flask debugging mode (it was set off for no reason, so I coudn't see the changes I made). Is there a trick to remove trailing slash for url_for() in flask? Thanks
Edit: I solved that, I forgot I added one myself, my bad. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for delimiters:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters

Comment: I get an `Error compiling template: invalid expression: Invalid regular expression flags in /slugwhatever/name` from Vue. The name is not replaced even though I'm using `v-bind:`. Note: I got that I have to change delimiters in order for Vue not to recognize the jinja tags as delimiters, but it's not working. Note: I'm using vue from a cdn for a quick test.